# Nginx Proxy/ Apache - cache static file or duplicate to nginx server

Tags: apache, nginx

It setup wordpress on apache server and config it runs smooth.

Now i want to setup a nginx proxy to server static files.

So i have some questions:

1. Do i need to duplicate uploads folder of wordpress and put in nginx server ?
   Or try to cache all static file in nginx server ?
2. On apache server i use module deflate, expires, pagespeed, opcache. So if i add nginx proxy to server static files, should i remove the deflate, expires, pagespee module ? Because we can do this work on nginx server.

Comment: You're going to need to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using Nginx, the Apache HTTPD sever is good but redundant. Nginx can communicate to PHP-FPM directly which is the most efficient solution so far, with that option you can do:

- improve performance
- simplify deployment procedure
- setup gzip and other headers in one place
- serve static content more efficiently
- reduce amount of overall memory
- utilise Nginx cache (with Wordpress plugin to invalidate its cache on page content update)

Comment: I know we do not need the apache. But in this case, i only want to use nginx as a cache proxy.